# Ignoring a client when broadcasting a message with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to ignore the client that made the request to broadcast the message my web app. The only way I can seem to do this is by caching the connectionId of the current user:

```
public class BroadcastHub : Hub
{

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Set(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "-connectionId", Context.ConnectionId, new CacheItemPolicy() { Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default, SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1), AbsoluteExpiration = MemoryCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration });

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Set(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "-connectionId", Context.ConnectionId, new CacheItemPolicy() { Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default, SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1), AbsoluteExpiration = MemoryCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration });

        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

}
```

This allows me to do the following in the controller action method:

```
        IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BroadcastHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.AllExcept((string)MemoryCache.Default.Get(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "-connectionId")).sendAddedPasswordDetail(addedPassword);
```

This method seems to work... but I'm thinking it might be the wrong way of doing things. Is there a better way to ignore the requesting client?

Comment: What you have done is correct. I have in the past used a Keyvalue store that associates a userid with a connection id in the collection. Then just filter out the user who made the request using LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

There is a specific property that allows this particular exception,

```
hubContext.Clients.Others.YourMethodHere
```

You can see it used [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client).

**Edit:**
As per the discussion in the comments, `Others` is not available when using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<T>`

You will either need to continue using your current method or find a way to delegate this activity to the `BroadcastHub` to have access to `Others`.

Comment: Yeah. I've seen the Others property in documentation... but version 2.1.2 doesn't appear to have it.

Comment: It should be there, though it may not be on the IHubContext interface, I do seem to recall having an issue getting the correct interface for that.

Comment: @binks I dug through the src a bit and I was correct the Others property appears on the TypedHubCallerConnectionContext class which appears to be inherited by the hub, I am not immediately aware if its possible to get access to that through GlobalHost method.